# javascript setAttribute replacement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to javascript and have problem when play with w3school's example.
Here is the link the problem from
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete

The original sample code for its HTML is

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And part of original sample javascript

```
a = document.createElement("DIV");
a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
/*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
/*for each item in the array...*/
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {...
```

while I replace the HTML to

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
    <div class="autocomplete-items" style="display:none"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

the style part I actually did it within css style.

and change the javascript to

```
a = document.querySelector(".autocomplete-items");
a.style.display = "block";
```

replace the following and keep the rest of the original code.

```
a = document.createElement("DIV");
a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
/*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
```

I think the result should be the same but turn out it did not work.
Is there anything wrong with my thought?
I want to skip the createElement part and make it done by html with css display property.

Comment: The `autocomplete-items` container is removed everytime `function closeAllLists(elmnt)` is called (`x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);`), and since you're no longer creating it dynamically it never gets replaced. The example code is fine, and it's not a problem with w3schools, but with debugging. Try inspecting the DOM and following the thread of the code to see what might have broken.

Comment: You can 'fix' it by not removing the container, but by hiding it, so `x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);` becomes `x[i].style.display = 'none';`

Comment: why are you using setAttribute for classes? use `el.classList.add("class")`

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work when applying the changes you made is because the function `closeAllLists()` removes any element with classname `autocomplete-items`, so also the div that contains all the autocomplete elements.

I applied some changes to your code to make it work:

In the html i gave your div an id of `autocomplete-items-container`.

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
    <div id="autocomplete-items-container"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and made some changes in the javascript:

```
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
   var a = document.querySelector('#autocomplete-items-container');
   etc.
```

```
function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll("#autocomplete-items-container > *");
    etc.
```

```
inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.querySelector('#autocomplete-items-container');
      etc.
```

Note that i'd recomment changing some of the variable names to make the code more readable for yourself, especially if you're new to javascript.

For example, how about changing `a` to `container`, `b` to `listItem` and `x` to `allItems` for example?

Good luck on your learning journey! Hope this was somewhat helpful.